# Ruby - Calling all methods without arguments for a class object

Tags: ruby, reflection

Is it possible to call all parameterless methods for a given class object by using reflection in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

```
def call_paramater_less_methods(instance)
   instance.class.instance_methods(false).each do |m|
     instance.public_send(m) if instance.method(m).arity.zero?
   end
end

class C
  def a()  puts "a says hi"   end
  def b()  puts "b says ho"   end
  def c(s) puts "c says #{s}" end
end

call_paramater_less_methods(C.new)
  # b says ho
  # a says hi
```

Optionally,

```
instance.public_send(m) if instance.method(m).arity.zero?
```

can be replaced with

```
instance.method(m).call if instance.method(m).arity.zero?
```

Comment: And then call them with `send` or `public_send` or get the method objects and use `call` (`m = obj.method(name); m.call`).  The "class object" terminology makes me think they're talking about class methods but the procedure is pretty much the same.

Comment: @muistooshort, I see I did not answer the question that was asked. Thanks for letting me know. I've done an edit.